# Renaming CoreData classes while allowing App updates

Tags: database, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have made the mistake when starting the coding an iPhone App of not adding a prefix to my classnames, and as such have a conflict (A CoreData class called Category). The project build fine until the recent update of Xcode, and only now I realize the mistake.

Is it possible to rename CoreData classes while keeping a working system after update? 
If I add a new version to the Datamodel and rename the class, the App updates, but it seems that the old table is deleted and a new (empty) one created. Obviously all the links subsequently are broken. I would like to maintain the data while making the change.

In Java EE you can overrule the table name if I remember correctly, and as such I could stick to the old class name to name the table. Is there any such possibility with CoreData?

Thanks in advance! I have to find a way to update the DB without all the Apps out in the field breaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it i documented quite well by Apple:

> If you rename an entity or property,
>   you can set the renaming identifier in
>   the destination model to the name of
>   the corresponding property or entity
>   in the source model. You typically set
>   the renaming identifier using the
>   Xcode Data Modeling tool, (for either
>   an NSEntityDescription or an
>   NSPropertyDescription object). In
>   Xcode, the renaming identifier is in
>   the User Info pane of the Detail Pane,
>   below the version hash modifier (see
>   The Browser View in Xcode Tools for
>   Core Data). ([Mac OS X Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) )

But actually for me it seems to work just to change the Classname and leave the rest of the model alone.

Comment: Isn't that documentation only relevant to renaming the entity itself and not to just the underlying class?  So if I have a "Car" entity in the CoreData model that is currently mapped to class "Car" and I want to rename the associated class to "MYCar" (leaving entity stil named "Car") I don't think this applies.  I guess that's why it works if you just change the class name in the model.